# Netbeans "Import Classes" Error Message

Tags: java, netbeans

When I copy codes from one file and paste it to another, a message dialogue opens as "Import Classes" says, "Pasted code refers to the following not imported elements, resolve imports to include them?"

[image]

After "OK" then IDE gives message, as in following images (since one does not need to import java.lang classes),

[image]

and,

[image]

IDE otherwise compiles and runs correctly with no problem.

Environment : NetBeans IDE 8.0 running Java programs on Windows 8.1, Java (JRE, JDK) 8.xx

Comment: What error message are you talking about?

Comment: @jeroen Even adding the "import" line wouldn't prevent the message. The message actually should not appear at all. It is an error of IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could ignore if the warning was not persistent or had a check box for not showing the message anymore.

Already, unrelated to this warning, I needed to upgrade Java JDK. So I uninstalled NetBeans 8.0 and Java JDK all together. I installed the latest JDK and installed NetBeans 8.0.2. Now it works fine.

I suppose copying automatic code lines created by NetBeans IDE visual forms and paste them in another file may cause such a problem. At the moment I have no such issue.

Answer (score 1):

In a Java file, the `java.lang` package is implicitly imported, so the suggestion that you should add imports for any `java.lang` class is not a good suggestion.

If you see that, you should ignore it.

It looks like there's a [bug report](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104908) on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no so serious problem. Hint and importing classes on paste are unrelated, simply importing classess functionality not checks from where it imports classes.